# Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance payment blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Do anyone has an idea about this error:

```
Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: D:\projet7899\laravel-only-school-managemnt\resources\views\backend\payment\edit.blade.php)
```

payment/edit.blade.php

```
<div class="table w-full mt-8 bg-white rounded">
            <form action="{{ route('payment.update',$payment->id) }}" method="POST" class="w-full max-w-xl px-6 py-12">
                @csrf
```

Do anyone has an idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Double check your controller is returning a model instance for `$payment` instead of a collection. For example, use `->first()` instead of `->get()`.

Comment: public function update(Request $request, Payment $payment)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',

        ]);

        $payment->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
        ]);

Comment: Is this the controller method that returns the `edit` view?

Comment: public function edit(Payment $payment)
    {
        $payment = Payment::latest()->get();
        return view('backend.payment.edit', compact('payment'));
    }

Comment: change `$payment = Payment::latest()->get();` to `$payment = Payment::latest()->first();` to get a single latest payment